# DLL method needs to wait for form to send back reference variables before continuing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dll which contains a method which displays a form and passes it an object and two reference variables:

```
public void MyMethod(..variables, ref DataString, ref DataCount) 
{
    // Code to create object..
    Form myForm = New Form(MyObject, ref DataString, ref DataCount);
    myForm.Show();
}
```

However, I don't want the method to close until the user has done a load of stuff on "myForm" and I know the reference variables are populated.

What is the best way to make MyMethod wait until the user is finished on the form before exiting?

Comment: Have you made sure the Form is Modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

This will force `MyMethod` to wait until `myForm` is closed.

Comment: Thanks.  That is working.  I'm sure I had tried that!  Am I correct in thinking that absolutely no more code will run in "MyMethod" until myForm has done all of its processing (no matter how complex and protracted"?

Comment: Done.  I think I was getting confused as I was instantiating the form via a COM Interface and I thought that ShowDialog required a parent form.

Comment: Sometimes it is right in front of you and you don't see it or you tried it and did not realise it worked! Those are the worst errors!